# RuntimeEror when using asset .js.coffee file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I'm just getting started using rails 3.1 and jQuery / coffee scripts.  I have a piece of js code which works when included in a  tag in my view but when included in app/assets/javascripts/post.js.coffee it throws the following error:

> ExecJS::RuntimeError in Posts#new
>
> Showing
>   /home/chris/RailsDev/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where
>   line #10 raised:
>
> Reserved word "function" on line 7   (in
>   /home/chris/RailsDev/blog/app/assets/javascripts/post.js.coffee)

**This works:**

app/views/posts/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@user, @post] do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :title %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :content %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :content %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="forward_date">Post in the future?</label>
        <%= check_box_tag 'forward date' %>
        <div id="post_date" style="display: none;">
          <%= f.label :post_date %>
          <%= f.datetime_select :post_date %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <script>
      $("#forward_date").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $("#post_date").show("slow");
        } else {
          $("#post_date").hide("slow");
        }
      });
    </script>
```

**This throws ExecJS::RuntimeError**

Remove the  tag from the view and place the code in app/assets/javascripts/post.js.coffee

```
$("#forward_date").change(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#post_date").show("slow");
  } else {
    $("#post_date").hide("slow");
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the coffeescript isn't coffeescript

should be:

```
$("#forward_date").change ->
  if $(this).is(":checked")
    $("#post_date").show "slow"
  else
    $("#post_date").hide "slow"
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not how you declare a function in Coffeescript. Instead of the keyword `function` use `->`:

```
$("#forward_date").change -> 
  if $(this).is ":checked"  
    $("#post_date").show "slow"
  else
    $("#post_date").hide "slow"
```